# XPath html nodes with custom namespace attributes

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I use c# .NET 6 with [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net) Nuget Package version 1.11.46 installed and i am facing the following problem:

```html
<span my:fdivid="1">Test1</span> // should be selected
<span id="2">Test2</span>        // should NOT be selected
<div my:fdivid="3">Test3</span>  // should be selected
```

I want to get all the html nodes that have a `my:fdivid` attribute so what i am doing is

```cs
// Create the HtmlDocument instance
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();

// Load the HTML document
htmlDoc.Load("path/to/your/html/file.html");

// Select nodes with the "my:fdivid" attribute
var nodesWithFdivAttribute = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@my:fdivid]");
```

The problem is that i am getting the error:

```
Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.
```

So after looking up the error i found solutions like

```cs
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.Load("path/to/your/html/file.html");

// Create a custom XmlNameTable
XmlNameTable nameTable = new NameTable();

// Create a XmlNamespaceManager with the custom XmlNameTable
XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("my", "http://example.com/your-namespace-uri");

var nodesWithFdivAttribute = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@my:fdivid]", namespaceManager);
```

The problem here is that `SelectNodes` does not support taking a `XmlNamespaceManager`.

So is there any way that i can select the elements that have the `my:fdivid` custom attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The comments in [the source code on the `HtmlNavigator`](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/08aae949868908de457a77668a9489d73f0280b9/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/HtmlNodeNavigator.cs) class (which is used in XPath queries) indicate that namespaces are not supported.

If the HTML is valid XHTML, you could load it into `XDocument` instead. You would need to add the HTML DTD for that.

The below answer does not actually work. I'm going to leave it for interest's sake.

---

Looking at the [source code for the `SelectNodes` function](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/08aae949868908de457a77668a9489d73f0280b9/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/HtmlNode.Xpath.cs#L40), you could use the following extension method:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> SelectNodes(
  this HtmlNode node, string xpath, IXmlNamespaceResolver resolver)
{
    var nav = node.CreateNavigator();
    var it = nav.Select(xpath, resolver);
    while (it.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return ((HtmlNodeNavigator) it.Current).CurrentNode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now implemented a workaround that fixed the issue... but im still wondering why its not possible over an XPath Expression:

```cs
// first select ALL nodes
var allNodes = _htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*");
// filter them for desired Attributes
var nodesWithFdivAttribute = allNodes.Where(n => n.Attributes.Any(a => a.Name == "my:fdivid"));
```

Would still be glad about a better solution

**Edit**

I found a way on how to solve it with XPath:

```cs
var nodesWithFdivAttribute = _htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($"//*[@*[local-name()='my:fdivid']]");
```